# Autohotkey - How to adjust volume only of a specific program?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to control volume of a specific program and not the whole master volume.

I found [THIS](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/56889-application-specific-sound-control-for-windows-7-rev-101/) thread that has code for controlling only the volume of Windows Media Player from Volume Mixer .

This is the whole script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 3
SndVolWasStarted = 0

;Turn off SndVol after 1 second 
Loop {
  Sleep, 10
  If SndVolWasStarted = 1
  {
    GetKeyState, StateF1, F1
    GetKeyState, StateF2, F2
    If (StateF1 = "D" or StateF2 = "D")
    SndVolStartTime = %A_Now%
      Else {
        If ((A_Now - SndVolStartTime > 1) and WinExist("ahk_class #32770"))
        WinClose, ahk_class #32770
      }
    IfWinNotExist, ahk_class #32770
    SndVolWasStarted = 0
  }
}

;Hotkey to decrease volume
F1::
IfWinExist, Windows Media Player 
{
  IfWinNotExist, ahk_class #32770
  {
    Run, "%A_WinDir%\System32\SndVol.exe" -r 88888888
    WinWait, ahk_class #32770
    SndVolWasStarted = 1
  }
  ToolbarWindowNumber = 322
  msctls_trackbarNumber = 321
  Loop {
    ControlGetText, ControlName, ToolbarWindow%ToolbarWindowNumber%, ahk_class #32770
    If ControlName = Mute for Windows Media Player
    {
      ControlSend, msctls_trackbar%msctls_trackbarNumber%, {Down}, ahk_class #32770 ; Use {Down 2} to change sound level faster
      Break
    } Else {
      If ToolbarWindowNumber < 328
      {
        ToolbarWindowNumber := ToolbarWindowNumber + 2
        msctls_trackbarNumber := msctls_trackbarNumber + 1
      } Else {
        If ToolbarWindowNumber = 328
        {
          ToolbarWindowNumber = 3210
          msctls_trackbarNumber := msctls_trackbarNumber + 1
        } Else {
          If ToolbarWindowNumber < 3242
          {
            ToolbarWindowNumber := ToolbarWindowNumber + 2
            msctls_trackbarNumber := msctls_trackbarNumber + 1
          } Else {
            MsgBox, 16, AutoHotkey, ERROR: Application's volume control was not found!`nThis could occur if the Volume Mixer has more than 20 opened applications
            Break
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
Return

;Hotkey to increase volume
F2::
IfWinExist, Windows Media Player
{
  IfWinNotExist, ahk_class #32770
  {
    Run, "%A_WinDir%\System32\SndVol.exe" -r 88888888
    WinWait, ahk_class #32770
    SndVolWasStarted = 1
  }
  ToolbarWindowNumber = 322
  msctls_trackbarNumber = 321
  Loop {
    ControlGetText, ControlName, ToolbarWindow%ToolbarWindowNumber%, ahk_class #32770
    If ControlName = Mute for Windows Media Player
    {
      ControlSend, msctls_trackbar%msctls_trackbarNumber%, {Up}, ahk_class #32770 ; Use {Up 2} to change sound level faster
      Break
    } Else {
      If ToolbarWindowNumber < 328
      {
        ToolbarWindowNumber := ToolbarWindowNumber + 2
        msctls_trackbarNumber := msctls_trackbarNumber + 1
      } Else {
        If ToolbarWindowNumber = 328
        {
          ToolbarWindowNumber = 3210
          msctls_trackbarNumber := msctls_trackbarNumber + 1
        } Else {
          If ToolbarWindowNumber < 3242
          {
            ToolbarWindowNumber := ToolbarWindowNumber + 2
            msctls_trackbarNumber := msctls_trackbarNumber + 1
          } Else {
            MsgBox, 16, AutoHotkey, ERROR: Application's volume control was not found!`nThis could occur if the Volume Mixer has more than 20 opened applications
            Break
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
Return
```

I tried it and it works with Windows Media Player but I can't make it to work on Google Chrome.

I changed some piece of code on `IfWinExist, Windows Media Player` and changed it to `IfWinExist, Google Chrome` but didn't adjust the volume of Chrome.

I'm running windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Does the answer worked for you? If yes, please accept answer.

Answer (score 5):

1. Replace all `IfWinExist, Windows Media Player`
   with `IfWinExist ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1`
2. Replace all `If ControlName = Mute for Windows Media Player`
   with `if (ControlName ~= "Mute for.*- Google Chrome")`

You can use Autohotkey Window Spy utility to find the values. Rightclick any AHK icon in the taskbar tray notification area and select "Window Spy".

---

**Or use the awesome [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) utility:**

```
^#Up::run nircmd changeappvolume focused +0.1
^#Down::run nircmd changeappvolume focused -0.1
^#Numpad0::run nircmd muteappvolume focused 2
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> = volume up active app
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> = volume down active app
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> = mute/unmute active app

Replace `focused` with app exe name to control a specific app, e.g. `chrome.exe`, `vlc.exe`

Comment: changed the script to this: hastebin.com/ewizedidov.cmake then this message appeared i.snag.gy/SznsOt.jpg

Comment: Well that's because Chrome wasn't playing anything, so it wasn't listed. Simply delete the `msgbox` lines.

Comment: Chrome and Windows Media Player works but how about others like VLC etc... What code will put next to `IfWinExist ` ?

Comment: You can use Autohotkey Window Spy utility to find the values.

Comment: Do you know how to mute/unmute it as well?

Answer (score 1):

I had some annoying latency using `nircmd`. Here is my solution:

`ShiftAppVolume( appName, incr )`, with:

- `appName`: Name of the target .exe. If empty (e.g., `""`), the application of the active window is used.
- `incr`: An increment as a ratio of the master volume (e.g., `0.04` or `-0.20`). If `0`, the function acts as a toggle mute/unmute for the application.

You can “go” above 100% of the master volume: the master volume is then automatically increased, and the other apps are lowered accordingly to keep a constant level. (The function also ensures that there is an app at 100%, so that if you increase then reduce the level of an app, the master volume isn't kept high for no good reason.)

```
ShiftAppVolume( appName, incr )
{
    if !appName
    {
        WinGet, activePID, ID, A
        WinGet, activeName, ProcessName, ahk_id %activePID%
        appName := activeName        
    }
    
    IMMDeviceEnumerator := ComObjCreate( "{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}", "{A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6}" )
    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IMMDeviceEnumerator+0 ) + 4*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IMMDeviceEnumerator, "UInt", 0, "UInt", 1, "UPtrP", IMMDevice, "UInt" )
    ObjRelease(IMMDeviceEnumerator)

    VarSetCapacity( GUID, 16 )
    DllCall( "Ole32.dll\CLSIDFromString", "Str", "{77AA99A0-1BD6-484F-8BC7-2C654C9A9B6F}", "UPtr", &GUID)
    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IMMDevice+0 ) + 3*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IMMDevice, "UPtr", &GUID, "UInt", 23, "UPtr", 0, "UPtrP", IAudioSessionManager2, "UInt" )

    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IAudioSessionManager2+0 ) + 5*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IAudioSessionManager2, "UPtrP", IAudioSessionEnumerator, "UInt" )
    ObjRelease( IAudioSessionManager2 )
    
    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IAudioSessionEnumerator+0 ) + 3*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IAudioSessionEnumerator, "UIntP", SessionCount, "UInt" )
    levels := []
    maxlevel := 0
    targets := []
    t := 0
    ISAVs := []
    Loop % SessionCount
    {
        DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IAudioSessionEnumerator+0 ) + 4*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IAudioSessionEnumerator, "Int", A_Index-1, "UPtrP", IAudioSessionControl, "UInt" )
        IAudioSessionControl2 := ComObjQuery( IAudioSessionControl, "{BFB7FF88-7239-4FC9-8FA2-07C950BE9C6D}" )
        ObjRelease( IAudioSessionControl )
        
        DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IAudioSessionControl2+0 ) + 14*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IAudioSessionControl2, "UIntP", PID, "UInt" )
        
        PHandle := DllCall( "OpenProcess", "uint", 0x0010|0x0400, "Int", false, "UInt", PID )
        if !( ErrorLevel or PHandle = 0 )
        {
            name_size = 1023
            VarSetCapacity( PName, name_size )
            DllCall( "psapi.dll\GetModuleFileNameEx" . ( A_IsUnicode ? "W" : "A" ), "UInt", PHandle, "UInt", 0, "Str", PName, "UInt", name_size )
            DllCall( "CloseHandle", PHandle )
            SplitPath PName, PName
            
            if incr
            {
                t += 1
                
                ISimpleAudioVolume := ComObjQuery(IAudioSessionControl2, "{87CE5498-68D6-44E5-9215-6DA47EF883D8}")
                DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( ISimpleAudioVolume+0 ) + 4*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", ISimpleAudioVolume, "FloatP", level, "UInt" )  ; Get volume
                
                if ( PName = appName )
                {
                    level += incr
                    targets.push( t )
                    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( ISimpleAudioVolume+0 ) + 5*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", ISimpleAudioVolume, "Int", 0, "UPtr", 0, "UInt" )  ; Unmute
                }
                ISAVs.push( ISimpleAudioVolume )
                levels.push( level )
                maxlevel := max( maxlevel, level )
            }
            else
            {
                if ( PName = appName )
                {
                    ISimpleAudioVolume := ComObjQuery(IAudioSessionControl2, "{87CE5498-68D6-44E5-9215-6DA47EF883D8}")
                    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( ISimpleAudioVolume+0 ) + 6*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", ISimpleAudioVolume, "IntP", muted )  ; Get mute status
                    maxlevel := maxlevel or muted
                    ISAVs.push( ISimpleAudioVolume )
                }
            }
        }
        ObjRelease(IAudioSessionControl2)
    }
    ObjRelease(IAudioSessionEnumerator)
    
    if incr
    {
        if ( maxlevel = 0.0 ) or ( maxlevel = 1.0 )
        {
            for i, t in targets
                DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( ISAVs[t]+0 ) + 3*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", ISAVs[t], "Float", levels[t], "UPtr", 0, "UInt" )
        }
        else
        {
            VarSetCapacity( GUID, 16 )
            DllCall( "Ole32.dll\CLSIDFromString", "Str", "{5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A}", "UPtr", &GUID)
            DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IMMDevice+0 ) + 3*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IMMDevice, "UPtr", &GUID, "UInt", 7, "UPtr", 0, "UPtrP", IEndpointVolume, "UInt" )

            DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IEndpointVolume+0 ) + 9*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IEndpointVolume, "FloatP", MasterLevel ) ; Get master level
            DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IEndpointVolume+0 ) + 7*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IEndpointVolume, "Float", MasterLevel * maxlevel, "UPtr", 0, "UInt" ) ; Set master level
            ObjRelease( IEndpointVolume )
            
            for i, ISimpleAudioVolume in ISAVs
                DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( ISimpleAudioVolume+0 ) + 3*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", ISimpleAudioVolume, "Float", min( 1.0, levels[i] / maxlevel ) , "UPtr", 0, "UInt" )  ; Set volume
        }        
    }
    else
    {
        for i, ISimpleAudioVolume in ISAVs
            DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( ISimpleAudioVolume+0 ) + 5*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", ISimpleAudioVolume, "Int", !maxlevel, "UPtr", 0, "UInt" )  ; Toggle mute status
    }
    ObjRelease( IMMDevice )
    for i, ISimpleAudioVolume in ISAVs
        ObjRelease(ISimpleAudioVolume)
}
```

If you want to be capped by the current Master Volume (i.e., once your application is at 100% relative level, trying to increase will have no effect), you can use:

```
ShiftAppVolumeTopped( appName, incr )
{
    if !appName
    {
        WinGet, activePID, ID, A
        WinGet, activeName, ProcessName, ahk_id %activePID%
        appName := activeName        
    }
    
    IMMDeviceEnumerator := ComObjCreate( "{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}", "{A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6}" )
    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IMMDeviceEnumerator+0 ) + 4*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IMMDeviceEnumerator, "UInt", 0, "UInt", 1, "UPtrP", IMMDevice, "UInt" )
    ObjRelease(IMMDeviceEnumerator)

    VarSetCapacity( GUID, 16 )
    DllCall( "Ole32.dll\CLSIDFromString", "Str", "{77AA99A0-1BD6-484F-8BC7-2C654C9A9B6F}", "UPtr", &GUID)
    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IMMDevice+0 ) + 3*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IMMDevice, "UPtr", &GUID, "UInt", 23, "UPtr", 0, "UPtrP", IAudioSessionManager2, "UInt" )
    ObjRelease( IMMDevice )

    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IAudioSessionManager2+0 ) + 5*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IAudioSessionManager2, "UPtrP", IAudioSessionEnumerator, "UInt" )
    ObjRelease( IAudioSessionManager2 )
    
    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IAudioSessionEnumerator+0 ) + 3*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IAudioSessionEnumerator, "UIntP", SessionCount, "UInt" )
    Loop % SessionCount
    {
        DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IAudioSessionEnumerator+0 ) + 4*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IAudioSessionEnumerator, "Int", A_Index-1, "UPtrP", IAudioSessionControl, "UInt" )
        IAudioSessionControl2 := ComObjQuery( IAudioSessionControl, "{BFB7FF88-7239-4FC9-8FA2-07C950BE9C6D}" )
        ObjRelease( IAudioSessionControl )
        
        DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( IAudioSessionControl2+0 ) + 14*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", IAudioSessionControl2, "UIntP", PID, "UInt" )
        
        PHandle := DllCall( "OpenProcess", "uint", 0x0010|0x0400, "Int", false, "UInt", PID )
        if !( ErrorLevel or PHandle = 0 )
        {
            name_size = 1023
            VarSetCapacity( PName, name_size )
            DllCall( "psapi.dll\GetModuleFileNameEx" . ( A_IsUnicode ? "W" : "A" ), "UInt", PHandle, "UInt", 0, "Str", PName, "UInt", name_size )
            DllCall( "CloseHandle", PHandle )
            SplitPath PName, PName
            if ( PName = appName )
            {
                ISimpleAudioVolume := ComObjQuery(IAudioSessionControl2, "{87CE5498-68D6-44E5-9215-6DA47EF883D8}")
                DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( ISimpleAudioVolume+0 ) + 6*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", ISimpleAudioVolume, "IntP", muted )  ; Get mute status
                if incr
                {
                    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( ISimpleAudioVolume+0 ) + 4*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", ISimpleAudioVolume, "FloatP", level, "UInt" )  ; Get volume
                    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( ISimpleAudioVolume+0 ) + 3*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", ISimpleAudioVolume, "Float", max( 0.0, min( 1.0, level + incr ) ) , "UPtr", 0, "UInt" )  ; Set volume
                    if muted
                        DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( ISimpleAudioVolume+0 ) + 5*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", ISimpleAudioVolume, "Int", !muted , "UPtr", 0, "UInt" )  ; Unmute
                }
                else
                {
                    DllCall( NumGet( NumGet( ISimpleAudioVolume+0 ) + 5*A_PtrSize ), "UPtr", ISimpleAudioVolume, "Int", !muted , "UPtr", 0, "UInt" )  ; Set volume
                }
                ObjRelease(ISimpleAudioVolume)
            }
        }
        ObjRelease(IAudioSessionControl2)
    }
    ObjRelease(IAudioSessionEnumerator)
}
```

Credit is due: those solution have been created by expanding [this proposition](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=46654), with additional hints from [GeekDude's AppVolume](https://gist.github.com/anonymous1184/c06335f3aed215cdea414c33354a728b#file-appvolume-ahk-L26). The latter is a class that you could also use directly in your code.